# Can Thymeleaf access the Spring servletContext?

Tags: spring-webflow-2, thymeleaf

I wonder if anyone can help. We are in the process of converting a Spring Webflow 2 application from using a jsp based view layer, to a Thymeleaf based view.

For this most part this is OK, but now I'm struggling to get Thymeleaf to access an object that we've put in the `servletContext`.

So, we have an object that is put in the `servletContext` as part of a bean (implementing `ServletContextAware` and `InitializingBean`)

For the sake of simplicity, lets say it is a string:

```
public class ReferenceDataBuilder implements ServletContextAware, InitializingBean {

public void setServletContext(ServletContext p_context) {
    p_context.setAttribute("referenceData", "test text" );
}
```

In our jsp based views, we can access the `referenceData` object like this:

```
<p><c:out value="${referenceData}"/></p>
```

By the magic of Spring EL, it knows the various scopes it has access to (`servletContext`, `flowScope`, `flashScope` etc), and (I'm guessing?) searches each scope until it finds a matching property. The result is that:

```
<p>test text</p>
```

is rendered within the view.

In our thymeleaf template, we are trying to do the same thing:

```
<p th:text="${referenceData}"/></p>
```

But this simply returns an empty string. The view renders an empty string:

```
<p></p>
```

(but I think the EL is actually being returned as a null)

I'm pretty sure that if the `referenceData` object were a property of a scope such as `flowScope` or `flashScope` this would work - but its not, its a property of `servletContext`.

Does anyone know if thymeleaf can access the `servletContext` via EL? Perhaps theres a different syntax I need to use?

Cheers

Nathan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could access usual maps via the #ctx object, which is of type [SpringWebContext](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring3/2.0.14/org/thymeleaf/spring3/context/SpringWebContext.html).

For example #ctx.locale, #ctx.httpServletRequest.contextPath, #ctx.servletContext or even #ctx.applicationContext for Spring applicationContext.

You could use direct method invocation

```
<p th:text="${#ctx.servletContext.getAttribute('referenceData')}">Whatever</p>
```

or the applicationAttributes variables map

```
<p th:text="${#ctx.servletContext.applicationAttributes.referenceData}">Whatever</p>
```

or event simpler using Spring implicit object

```
<p th:text="${application.referenceData}">Whatever</p>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do `${#ctx.getContextPath()}` but that gives me an error like as if that method doesn't exist. Can I call `${#ctx.getContextPath()}` in Thymeleaf?

Comment: @trusktr the way to do that is probably using `${#httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}`