# Thymeleaf cannot get Spring @ApplicationScope Bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

According to Spring document, @ApplicationScope Beans are visible as ServletContext attributes if Spring IOC container is web-aware.

I know i can access to @ApplicationScope Beans using `${@beanName}` in thymeleaf template, but why can't I access to them using `${#servletContext.getAttribute('myAttribute')}` as thymeleaf document show?

Below is my code snippet.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private BranchService branchService;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(RetailStoreApplication.class, args);

    }

    @ApplicationScope
    @Bean(value = "branches")
    public List<Branch> branches() {

        return branchService.queryAllBranches();

    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
    public String home() {

        return "home.html";

    }

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>


        Below are all the branch, please choose one for this branch.
        <span th:if="${#servletContext.getAttribute('branches')} == null">NULL</span>
        <ul th:each="branch : ${#servletContext.getAttribute('branches')}">
            <li th:text="${branch.name}" />
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

The returning 'branches' result is null. I'm using spring-boot2 with web-starter and thymeleaf-starter.

Have already try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949107/can-thymeleaf-access-the-spring-servletcontext), but not work in my case.

Any response is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but what you are returning from the bean factory method is not a legal Spring Bean (List<Branches>)

Comment: >"Why can't I access to them using `${#servletContext...` ?" ..because it (application scoped bean) is not there! Why not access it as `${@branches}` ??

Comment: why not, @SimonMartinelli? are there any more restrictions/requirements on a "bean factory method" than to return a `java.lang.Object`(, which `List` is)?

Comment: ..i've just tried `@Bean public Class<System> system() { return System.class; }` .."works like charm" :)

Comment: @xerx593, But spring document said that '@ApplicationScope' Bean is scoped at the ServletContext level and stored as a regular ServletContext attribute. I'm using '${@branches}' right now but just wonder why we cannot access it through '${#servletContext...'?(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-application)

Comment: you are right, @MichaelOuyang , the doc is straightforward (you use 5.2.5?)... please try this thymeleaf snippet for "debugging": `<tr th:each="attr : ${#servletContext.getAttributeNames()}"> ...` (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#servletcontext-attributes)